# defining parameters of multiple types in Nim

Tags: parameter-passing, nim-lang

Say I have a two classes and a procedure that modifies either class in the same manner. How do I specify that a parameter can be either class (instead of rewriting or overloading the function for each class)? A simple example:

```
type 
  Class1[T] = object
    x: T

  Class2[T] = object
    x: T
    y: T

# this works fine
proc echoX[T](c: Class1[T]|Class2[T]) =
  echo c.x

# this does not work
proc addToX[T](c: var Class1[T]|Class2[T], val: T) =
  c.x += val


var c1: Class1[int]
var c2: Class2[int]

# this works fine
echoX(c1)
echoX(c2)

# this does not work
addToX(c1, 10)
addToX(c2, 100)
```

I get the following error.

```
Error: for a 'var' type a variable needs to be passed
```

If I use a separate procedure for each class, things work fine.

```
proc addToX[T](c: var Class1[T], val: T) =
  c.x += val

proc addToX[T](c: var Class2[T], val: T) =
  c.x += val
```

This is just a simple example where it's easy to rewrite the function. But I'm looking to do this for more complex classes and procedures. In some cases inheritance might be appropriate, but it doesn't seem like Nim classes can be passed as variables to procedures in place of the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bracket fixes this problem, otherwise the `var` just applies to `Class1[T]`:

```
proc addToX[T](c: var (Class1[T]|Class2[T]), val: T) =
```

You may run into another compiler bug with this later: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/1385

Maybe in your use case object variantes or inheritance and methods will work better.

Comment: That works. In the example I gave, inheritance might be better. Say I have `Class1[T] = object of RootObj` and  `Class2[T] = object of Class1[T]`. It appears that I still need to write the procedure as `proc addToX[T](c: var (Class1[T]|Class2[T]), val: T) =`. I would have expected that  `proc addToX[T](c: var Class1[T], val: T) =` would be sufficient, since Class2 inherits from Class1.